# How to use wild card in filename that needs to be parsed using Element Tree

Tags: python, xml, wildcard, elementtree

When I use a wild card for the code below it gives me an error but when I use the full filename it does not. How to use wildcards in the file name?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filename = sys.argv[2]

#file name is 'Data*.xml' as in the future it will change every month so need to use a wild card
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
```

> I get the error below:
>
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Data*.xml"

Comment: See `glob.glob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by doing getting all files in the current directory and check if it starts with the string.

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]

for f in files:
    if f.startswith(sys.argv[2]):
        filename = f

tree = ET.parse(filename)
```

There must be an easier way, I am not sure why `ET.parse` cannot handle wild cards.

Comment: `ElementTree.parse()`, much like Python's `open()` function, only accepts a literal. file name. What would it mean for it to open many files at the same time? You can easily loop over all matches with `glob.glob()` or the more modern `pathlib.Path.glob()` or like you do here with `os.listdir()` and open each one separately, or pick out and open the ones you want.